# Difference between name and toponym name?

Tags: geonames

When I query geoNames for its data, it typically returns the place name in two ways:

1) name and 2) toponymName

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [search documentation](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html):

> 'name' and 'toponymName'
>
> The response
> returns two name attributes. The
> 'name' attribute is a localized name,
> the preferred name in the language
> passed in the optional 'lang'
> parameter or the name that triggered
> the response in a 'startWith' search.
> The attribute 'toponymName' is the
> main name of the toponym as displayed
> on the google maps interface page or
> in the geoname file in the download.
> The 'name' attribute is derived from
> the alternate names.

So *name* has been localized based on the language parameter passed along with the query, and *toponymName* is the canonical name.